# How to implement a model layer in Node.js that consumes less memory?

Tags: node.js

Do you know what's the best approach to implement a model layer that consumes less memory in Node.js? I consider that there are these options :

1. An unique instance of a class (business object) with a bunch of methods to create, update, delete, read, etc, a certain entity.

   ```
   // UserModel.js

   var User = function() {
       this.create = function(data, callback){};
       this.delete = function(id, callback){};
       this.read = function(id, callback){};
       this.update = function(id, data, callback){};
       this.list = function(data, callback){};
   }

   module.exports = new User();

   // UserController.js

   User = require('UserModel');

   User.create({
       username : 'xxx', 
       password : 'yyy'
   },function(err, user){

   });
   ```
2. A class with common methods that will have many instances :

   ```
   // UserModel.js

   var User = function(data){
      this.data = data;
      this.save = function(callback){};
      this.update = function(callback){};
      this.delete = function(callback){};
   }

   User.prototype.list = function(){};
   User.prototype.getById = function(){};

   module.exports = User;

   // UserController.js 

   var User = require('UserModel');

   var user = new User({
       username : 'xxx',
       password : 'yyy'
   });

   user.save(function(err){
     //...
   });
   ```

My doubt is about memory consumption, because in the first approach there is only one instance of a class that handle data across the control layer and the database; whereas in the second approach could be possible that there will be many instances of the same class (100 users signing up at the same time), although one benefit could be a more comprehensive OOP.

Thanks.

Comment: For starters to minimize memory consumption, put all your methods on the prototype, not assigned uniquely to each instance in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your first proposition. You're passing a object instance to `module.exports`. There's no real need for a constructor if your object does not require multiple instances. You should probably define something along the lines of

```
var UserModel = {
   create: function(){},
   read: function(){},
   update: function(){},
   delete: function(){},
   list: function(){}
}

module.exports = UserModel;
```

Declaring a function takes up memory, though a negligible amount. But more importantly it doesn't really make sense to have a constructor in this scenario, and if I were contributing to your code I'd likely change it for sanity's sake.

As for your second proposition, its definitely more common to go about an implementation like this using an object with a constructor and using the `new` keyword to create instances for each document you create. However it would likely consume more memory, since you're creating many instances of the same object. For example, you receive JSON, parse it into an object, then you pass that object to the constructor, thus constructing an instance with inherited methods and properties from the model and the document. Though, again, this is negligible amount of memory increase, being that JavaScript is pass by reference.

I don't understand why you're concerned about memory usage in this scenario. It's unlikely that there is much you can do to drastically reduce the memory consumption in this case. Ultimately it would probably be most performant to completely disregard OOP and just create procedural code, though it would be very unmanageable it would likely have the smallest memory footprint. Though this is my point exactly, you should probably write what *makes the most sense*, not what consumes the least memory. Any minor change that you would make in effort to reduce memory footprint would likely be mostly counter productive in the long run, where as objects don't really take that much memory.

100 users passing a username and password of 30bytes each, would equal out to ~10kb(headers, and additional characters in JSON). If you're working on a system with a small amount of memory, then you should probably consider using a language where you can explicitly manage memory and has static typing(C, C++, Java). Not to mention the concurrency model of nodejs doesn't exactly mean that 100 requests coming in at the same time, that nodejs will process those 100 requests concurrently, some of them will likely respond and be garbage collected before the others even start to be processed.